# R: Have a table in a sort of One-Hot format. However, the sum of counts of each column doesnt sum up to the total number of rows

Tags: r

I have a data frame like so:

```
temp <- data.frame("a" = c(1,0,0,1,0,0), "b" = c("0","1", "0", "1", "0", "1"), 'c'=c("0","0", "1", "0", "1", "1"))
```

Essentially, I want to locate rows 4 and 6 as they have two values of 1, instead of 1. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare `temp` with 1 and use `rowSums` to count number of 1's in each row and get the row index where it is greater than 1.

```
which(rowSums(temp == 1) > 1)
#[1] 4 6
```

Using `apply`, this is similar :

```
which(apply(temp == 1, 1, sum) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can also use `Reduce` with `lapply`

```
which(Reduce(`+`, lapply(temp, `==`, 1)) > 1)
#[1] 4 6
```